# sf: SpatialGridDataFrame vs SpatialPixelsDataFrame: Processing, Visualization and Storage

Tags: raster, r, spatial-analyst, sf, sp

I'm trying to understand what are the differences between an SpatialGridDataFrame and SpatialPixelsDataFrame. My final goal is to process some raster (readed with raster package and tif format) and save it using sf writing tools.

I'm trying just this and, in large datasets, the conversion takes to long in both cases:

```
r <- raster('./raster/raster.tif')

# Change raster format to sf
r.sf1 <- st_as_sf(as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame"))
r.sf2 <- st_as_sf(as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"))
```

- Which one performs better in processing (reprojections, raster calcs)?
- Which one is less ram consuming?
- Which one has more capabilities for visualization?

Comment: Why are you even going via sp classes? Why not `as.data.frame(r)` and hence `st_as_sf(as.data.frame(r,xy=TRUE), coords=1:2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SpatialGrid` objects store the grid geometry in a `GridTopology` class which is a few numbers defining the grid size and dimensions. `SpatialPixels` stores the x and y coordinates for each pixel, unless the pixel value is `NA`.

So if you have a lot of `NA` values in your raster, `SpatialPixels` objects will be much smaller:

```
> r = raster(matrix(rep(NA,100*100),100,100))
> r[1,1]=99
> pna = as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
> object.size(pna)
5504 bytes
```

That's a 100x100 raster with only one non-NA value. Fill it with real numbers and:

```
> r = raster(matrix(rep(99,100*100),100,100))
> pna = as(r, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
> object.size(pna)
285472 bytes
```

its a lot bigger. The same process with SpatialGrid objects returns objects that are the same size:

```
> r = raster(matrix(rep(NA,100*100),100,100))
> r[1,1]=99
> gna = as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
> object.size(gna)
84472 bytes
> r = raster(matrix(rep(99,100*100),100,100))
> gna = as(r, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
> object.size(gna)
84472 bytes
```

This object is smaller than the full SpatialPixels object because SpatialPixels stores *three* values - x,y,value - for each pixel. This becomes more efficient in terms of memory when you have sparse rasters.

Questions about processing efficiency are impossible to say without specifics. The code might convert from one to the other under the hood. If your process is local - eg squaring the cell values - SpatialPixels might win for a sparse raster because the system doesn't have to go over the entire grid to ignore the NAs. But for a non-local process, eg smoothing, SpatialPixels may be slower because its slower to look for neighbouring pixels in a SpatialPixels structure than in a SpatialGrid structure where neighbours will always be at the same offset in memory.

Similarly for visualisations, except what you can do with one you can do with the other - they are representations of the same underlying data structure, so I can't imagine any way of visualising one can't be done with the other.